# Android - Logcat Launch timeout has expired

Tags: android

When running LogCat in Eclipse, the output to Logcat stops after the following message

```
 08-19 19:46:13.525: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
 08-19 19:46:13.702: WARN/ActivityManager(58): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43fd5c90 com.android.homeopathy/.symptomActivity}
```

What does this mean and why does the output to Logcat stop at this point?

Comment: +1 for me misreading "Logcat Launch" as "Longcat Launch" :)

Comment: is it coming on using native activity?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some mionor problems with Logcat in eclipse as well. I chose the easy way out and use [ddms](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) now.